# How to detect audio/microphone is in use when any other app using microphone in Android?

Tags: android, audio, microphone

In my Android application I have to show an alert that "Other app using microphone". How can detect that another app using microphone/audio when my app going to access audio/microphone because my app user can not hear audio when another app accessing it?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/57257059/2443657