# Detect other apps using the microphone android

Tags: android, background-service

I have an Accessibility service that processes the surrounding sound with a microphone, and a process runs every time the user says Hey.

The problem is that when I listen to the microphone in the background service, no other software can use the microphone.

One way is to listen to access events whenever an event is received from the software with a premium microphone and disable my application process for a short time. But this is a bit non-standard and does not work to some extent ... Is there a way to access the microphone in such a way that any other program can access the microphone at any time and my program will automatically receive sound ?? Something like channels in audio playback !!

Or the way I can hear that a program needs a microphone !!

Thanks ❤️

Comment: You can check if microphone is available for use: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22677749/how-to-check-if-android-microphone-is-available-for-use . If its not available, it means some other app is using it.