Is it possible to detect another app's foreground service for Microphone?
My situation: I need to detect, on newer versions of Android, if any App is using the Microphone (default recorder, for example).
I found a lot of options, but they only work for version < Android 10. Those codes fail to detect on recent Versions, because of the way things changed regarding foreground services or the ability to "kidnap" the usage of Mic. (at least that's what I managed to understand. correct me if I'm wrong, please)
Is it still possible to detect Apps actively recording audio from the Mic, that are not using VOICE_CALL or VOICE_COMMUNICATION?

No, it is very difficult to detect apps using the microphone on newer versions of Android (Android 10 and above) due to new security and privacy restrictions.

For futher information, check this related answer outlining the newer API usages: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77961223/5525657
