# How one can know if MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_RECOGNITION is available

Tags: android, mediarecorder

How to check programmatically if `MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_RECOGNITION` is available or not?

In documentation it says:

> Microphone audio source tuned for voice recognition if available,
>   behaves like DEFAULT otherwise.

If `VOICE_RECOGNITION` is not available I want to use MIC instead. How can I check if it available or not.

*My minimum SDK is 9.*

Answer (score 0):

There is no really way to check if a specific AudioSource is supported.

It's better to allow user to select any source so he could identify by himself what it is working for him.

I've made the test Compose app to detect which audio sources are supported (but use it only for testing, not in real apps):

[image]

The code is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77961233/7767664)

Answer (score -1):

Use condition:

[MediaRecorder.getAudioSourceMax()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html#getAudioSourceMax()[1]) >= [MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_RECOGNITION](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.AudioSource.html#VOICE_RECOGNITION[2])

Comment: it has nothing to do with checking if audio source is supported